# When we keep two images only one image is shown Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, layout

I need to solve this problem actually , I made a activity and I took two different images of different ratio and when I put two Images in them only one is showing why is that I have already done some fixing which are android:adjustViewBonds=true and many more but it isn't working, I am using URI instead of Bitmap any suggestions how can it be fixed I did every available method 
above is the xml file you can see two images inside constraint layout they both are parallel to each other when I keep the ratio of any image say 1:1 for image 1, 13:3 for image 2 or something like this 
all this doesn't work only one image displays any suggests how to make it work thanks
Thanks...Any Questions Kindly ask :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hgfgfh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/fdgfdg"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="172dp"
                android:layout_height="31dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="ghfhgf"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="37dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/moreitems_foreground" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="198dp"
                android:layout_height="302dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="39dip"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="198dp"
                android:layout_height="302dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="39dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@drawable/view_v_foreground" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/like"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_fd_foreground"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
                android:focusedByDefault="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pump" />

        </RelativeLayout>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sdfsdf"
            android:layout_width="411dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:text="Vsdfs"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_rfgfdrt_foreground" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your xml view you have some errors. In ImageView with id=@+id/image1 you should replace

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gfdfdg"
```

with

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image2"
```

and in ImageView with id=@+id/image2 you should replace

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dfgdfg"
```

with

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image1"
```

try it out and let me know is it working with replacements.

EDIT>
with this replacements set for image1 and image2

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: Did this sir didn’t worked not at all sir actually when I pasted the code I didn’t fixed these issues now all of them are fixed and it still isn’t working any suggestions why kindly pls ignore the name errors in real code they are fixed sir

Comment: Please see edited answer. Also how are you setting your photos on imageViews, are you adding photos programmatically?